What suffices to ensure that, given a natural numbers object $(N, z, s)$, $s \circ z \neq z$?
Define a natural numbers object $(N, z, s)$ for a category $\mathsf{C}$ in the standard way. For any $1 \overset{q}{\longrightarrow} A \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} A$ in $\mathsf{C}$ there is a unique $u$ making the usual diagram commute.

But suppose in $\mathsf{C}$ is comparatively impoverished, and the only arrows from any object $Y$ to itself are identity arrows. Then very boringly putting $N = 1$ and $z = s = 1_{id}$ gives us an NNO.
OK, so here's the question: what does it take to get something interesting where $s\circ z \neq z$ and we have an infinite number of different elements $1 \to N$?
Of course, in a non-degenerate topos, we can look at $1 \overset{\bot}{\longrightarrow} \Omega \overset{\neg}{\longrightarrow} \Omega$, and out will pop the desired result,  $s\circ z \neq z.$
But OK, suppose we don't assume $\mathsf{C}$ has a subobject classifier? What other (neat? weaker?) conditions on $\mathsf{C}$ ensure that if it has a NNO, then $s \circ z \neq z$?

Seems like merely $hom(1,X)$ having two distinct maps,$f,g$ for some $X$ works, since $q=f,$ $r:X\to 1\to^g X$ gives $r\circ q=g\neq q.$

If there is a natural number object, $1\to N\to N,$ then $N\neq 1$ iff there exists an $X$ with at least two distinct maps $1\to X.$
If $\hom(1,X)$ has one element, and $q:1\to X$ and $f: X\to X,$ then $f\circ q,q\in hom(1,X),$ and thus $f\circ q=q.$
On the other hand, if $g_1,g_2\in hom(1,X)$ are distinct, let $\pi:X\to 1$ be the unique map, and let $q=g_1, f=g_2\circ\pi: X\to X.$ Then $q=g_1$ and $f\circ q=g_2\circ(\pi\circ q)=g_2\neq g_1=s.$
